# program that asks the user to input a string with at least three characters and displays a new word with the word “car” after first three characters

Tags: python

In python how do you write a program that asks the user to input a string with at least three
characters and displays a new word with the word “car” after the
first and third characters in the string.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please share what have you tried till now? What problems are you facing?

Comment: Two helpful places to start are the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing `arr[p:q]` would give you the slice from index p up to q - 1.

```py
user_inp = input("Input a string of at least three chars.")
if len(user_inp) >= 3:
    print(user_inp[0] + "car" + user_inp[1:3] + "char" + user_inp[3:])
```